# detect mouse direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, direction

I am trying this code to detect if the mouse direction is going up or  down:

```
<html>  
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: red;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
var mY = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    mY = e.pageY;
    if (e.pageY < mY) {
        console.log('From Bottom');
        return;

    } else {
        console.log('From Top');
    }

});
```

However this code doesn't work was i expect. Console log always show "from top"

Any idea ?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2uV/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var mY = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {

    // moving upward
    if (e.pageY < mY) {
        console.log('From Bottom');

    // moving downward
    } else {
        console.log('From Top');
    }

    // set new mY after doing test above
    mY = e.pageY;

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are setting `my = e.pageY` before comparing it, which means the comparison will always be equal (and therefore false.)

try it like this

```
var mY = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {

    if (e.pageY < mY) {
        console.log('From Bottom');

    } else {
        console.log('From Top');
    }
    mY = e.pageY;

});
```

Comment: Be careful to remove the return statement here otherwise `mY` doesn't get set after upward mouse movement

Comment: How is it that that only answer, that is currently listed, that won't work is the highest rated answer?

Answer (score 1):

`e.pageY` is always equal to `mY` because you set `mY` to `e.pageY` just before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to set your `mY` value after determining the direction *(previously you were setting it prior - thus would always receive a specific result)*

**Code:**

```
//Values starts at middle of page
var mY = $('window').height()/2;

//Compares position to mY and Outputs result to console
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (e.pageY < mY) {
        console.log('Going Up');   
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Going Down');
    }
    mY = e.pageY;
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDWBA/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you use if/else it will always output 'Going Down', even though e.pageY == mY.

Use 2 if-statements instead!

```
var mY = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {

// moving upward
if (e.pageY < mY) {
    console.log('From Bottom');

// moving downward
}
if (e.pageY > mY) {
    console.log('From Top');
}

// set new mY after doing test above
mY = e.pageY;

});
```

just copied the code from macek and replaced the 'else' with an 'if(...)' btw

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it. This way you can detect direction changes:

```
var tempMouseY=0;
$('body')
.mousemove(function(e) {
    moveY = -(tempMouseY-e.pageY);
    tempMouseY = e.pageY;
    if (moveY<0) {
        console.log('From Bottom');
    } else {
        console.log('From Top');
    }

 });
```