# jQuery determine if mouse leaves from the side

Tags: jquery, events, mouse

I already have a script for mouse enter, but I can't figure out leave statement from side.
Objective is to animate .darker to enter from side which mouse does, and also leave to side where mouse leaved.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.article', function(e){
    if(e.offsetX < 10){
        side = "left";
        $('.darker', this).css('top', '0');
        $('.darker', this).css('left', '-325px');
        $('.darker', this).animate({
            left: 0
        },200,function(){});
    }
});
```

Do you have any idea how to determine leaving from side?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to figure out if the mouse enters an element from the left or the right side? If so, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575951/jquery-mouse-direction-plugin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450199/detect-mouse-direction.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out when mouse leaves the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mouse events, basically 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' are the events you want.

Skim through [this excellent link for mouse events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) for details

For a jQuery specific answer look at .mouseover() and .mouseout() in jQuery API docs